# When should services persist data?

Tags: c#, design

Is there a preferable way of when a service should persist data?

**Update**

Does this depend on if the services are public or internal?

Some services take entity objects as parameters to do some action on that object, update it's status or add some data to it. Should that service also persist changes to that object to the database(SaveChanges, Flush, ...) or should the caller who got/created that entity decide if and when to persist it?

*Making the inner service persist the data includes problems like: harder tests, can't use implicit database transactions, maybe many database roundtrips instead of one.*

---

It is best to describe this with an example:

```
public void PerformAction(int productId, int actionId)
{
    var product = productRepository.GetProduct(productId);
    var action = actionRepository.GetAction(actionId);

    actionService.PerformAction(product, action);

    //Should this be necessary?
    productRepository.Update(product);
}
```

This would be obvious but then the `PerformAction` could not have dependencies other than the model:

```
public void PerformAction(int productId, int actionId)
{
    var product = productRepository.GetProduct(productId);
    var action = actionRepository.GetAction(actionId);

    product.PerformAction(action);

    //Obviously necessary!
    productRepository.Update(product);
}
```

Comment: @MainMa I updated my question with a better description. Is this more clear? If not, what do you feel is missing?

Comment: @Snowman I updated my question with a better description. Is this more clear? If not, what do you feel is missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you explicitly save data, the best place to perform that is in a call at the end of the highest level method, the entry point to your service. That means you must divide your service methods into two categories, those that are public, entry level methods, and those that are internal methods, that should not save data.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a strong reason, you should use an ORM (Entity Framework, NHibernate).

When you work with an ORM, the objects that were returned from the database will be "observed" and you just run the "SaveChanges();" 
leaving the dirty work to the ORM;

The ORM will automatically check which entities need to be persisted and if there is no change to be made it just does nothing.

Because, even in your second example, the entity product could have a business rule where it does not change any attribute in certain cases.

```
public void PerformAction(int productId, int actionId)
{
    var product = productRepository.GetProduct(productId);
    var action = actionRepository.GetAction(actionId);

    actionService.PerformAction(product, action);

    productRepository.Context.SaveChanges();
}
```

If you prefer not to use an ORM, you can "reinvent the wheel" and use the same design patterns that they use:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern

http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html

About where you should run the "SaveChanges", it depends on which layers each their services are.

An approach that I like to use is put all "SaveChanges" in the application layer (of DDD).

References: https://dzone.com/articles/responsibilities-application

Comment: Than you for your answer. My question was not about to use ORM or not which I do. My question was about where to call "SaveChanges" or the appropriate. Within this action like you did or within actionService?

Comment: I improved my answer, just sorry my English :)